# Launching JAR with Process.Start: javaw.exe runs but "nothing happens"?

Tags: c#, java

Given the code. when the button is clicked nothing happens , i get no debug message etc in visual studio. However if i were to double click the .jar file in its folder i am able to run it. Anyone have any idea why?
Looking at Task manager when the button is clicked. javaw.exe is created but nothing happens.

```
private void btnKinderPuzzle_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Check if this program is opened
    if (IsProcessOpen("MTPuzzle"))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("KinderPuzzle is already running", "Kinder Package", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
    }
    else
    {
        Process.Start(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\Puzzle\\PuzzleGame\\MTPuzzle.jar");
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you debug your program to see that the path is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Process.Start("java.exe", 
              Path.Combine("-jar " + Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), 
                           "Puzzle\\PuzzleGame\\MTPuzzle.jar"));
```

Answer (score 1):

The path may be not correct. You might use instead

```
Process.Start(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Puzzle\\PuzzleGame\\MTPuzzle.jar"));
```

If stills, then I think the problem in the setting of Java. To solve this potential problem, create a file `run.cmd` near your `jar` file and write this code into:

```
java -jar "MTPuzzle.jar"
```

Then, use `Process.Start` to start the file `run.cmd`