# ffmpeg video comparison using java

Tags: java, ffmpeg

I am working on ffmpeg video comparison. I call ffmpeg video comparison command from java. After execute the command. The comparison process was stopped. If i kill the javaw.exe the command resume and working and result file was created.
Am using following code to execute the command:

```
String command2CompareVideos = "D:\\bin\\ffmpeg -y -i D:\\postVideo_16.mp4 -i D:\\postVideo_16.mp4 -filter_complex \"[1:v]format=yuva444p,lut=c3=128,negate[video2withAlpha],[0:v][video2withAlpha]overlay[out]\" -map [out] D:\\ResultVideo.mp4"

    String[] processCommand = { "cmd", "/c","CALL",  command2CompareVideos};
    Process imgComProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(processCommand);  
    imgComProcess.waitFor();
    BufferedReader ouPiutReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(imgComProcess.getInputStream()));
                String outPut = ouPiutReader.readLine();
                while(outPut != null){
                    outPut = ouPiutReader.readLine();
                    System.out.println("Output: "+outPut);
                }
```

Comment: Does your `ffmpeg` command work normally when run manually and unscripted?

Comment: Ya. Its working fine when i run from command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but just go through the link and it may help you to understand about JAVAW.EXE.

http://javapapers.com/core-java/java-vs-javaw-vs-javaws/

Comment: Try this 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11553599/launching-jar-with-process-start-javaw-exe-runs-but-nothing-happens

Comment: Actually my problem is, The command execution was stooped. I think the problem in my "ffmpeg command".